how to solve Russell's paradox in modal set theory?
I am currently reading Nil Barton's "Iterative Set Theory." at pp.42-45.
It explains that modal set theory resolves Russell's paradox, but I don't fully understand it.
If a set x satisfies the Russell property in a world w, stabability guarantees that x will satisfy x ∉ x in all subsequent worlds.
However, since the definition of x itself satisfies the Russell property, wouldn't x ∈ x be possible in the world where x is created?
It still seems like a problem, so I don't understand why it is said that it doesn't cause an issue.

Hard to answer this question without seeing the text you're looking at.  However this article deals with modal set theory and talks a lot about Russell's paradox. The point (from a quick scan) seems to be that in modal set theory sets are constructed by enumerating and expounding members (not by abstracting members from properties).

With that in mind, we can only properly talk about 'sets' when this expansion/enumeration is 'closed': there's a place where we can conceivably have collected all members of the set. Sets like Russell's problematic set — the set of all sets that do not contain themselves — are transfinite, and so not closable, and thus not properly sets in the way meant. I'm leaving this as a comment because it's not really my area of expertise; maybe someone else can explain it better.

@Ted Wrigley thanks for kindly. you means that in modal set theory, a set is a collection whose members are collected at some closed stage, so because Russell set is cant, then what is difference with original set theory? in zfc, it also can ban Russell set with just putting replacement; is it just increasing plausibility or explanation with naturalness?

Again, I'm not an expert here. But the traditional way of defining a set is to say something like "all objects with property X", without considering whether any particularly object with property X exists. It's a top-down formulation of a set. Modal set theory seems to use a bottom-up formulation, starting with members. And I believe this issue is specifically important to sets of sets: modal set theory approaches those through power sets, while standard set theory approaches it by asserting a fixed and complete abstract set. But we're scraping at the limits of my knowledge.

Here the act of creation of x does not retroactively allow x∈x in the first world of its creation. The creation of x already respects the modal constraints, including the stability of the Russell property via S4 transitivity axiom 4 to ensure hierarchical iterative nature of sets. So stability is built into the definition of how sets come into being. Russell's paradox is avoided in modal set theory because the modal framework imposes constraints on the existence and persistence of properties across worlds. Set cannot be defined in such a way that it violates modal stability condition per 4…
